# Save system in command pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, strategy-pattern, saving-data

I have a problem with saving tasks for my employees in Unity, c#. I have their tasks implemented like a command pattern with a method(coroutine) as the task algorithm. Now I have to save their tasks to disk and load them later to resume them.

Example:

task interface:

```
interface IEmployeeTask
{
    IEnumerator PerformTask();
}
```

employee.cs

```
...
public WorkOnTask(IEmployeeTask task)
{
    this.currentTask = task;
    StartCoroutine(task.PerformTask());
}
...
```

two task implementations:

```
class SomeTask1 : IEmployeeTask
{
    ...
    public SomeTask1(int someImportantParameter){...}

    public override IEnumerator PerformTask
    {
        assignedEmployee.GoThere();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => assignedEmployee.ReachedDestination);
        assignedEmployee.DoThis();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => assignedEmployee.DidThis);
        assignedEmployee.UseParameter(someImportantParameter);
    }

}
```

```
class SomeTask2
{
    ...
    public SomeTask2(SomeClass someImportantReference){...}

    public override IEnumerator PerformTask
    {
        IThinkYouKnowWhereThisIsGoing();
        LemmeJustUseSomeObject(someImportantReference);
        yield break;
    }
}
```

I cannot restart those tasks, so just creating tasks by new or Activator and assign references wont help.

I could create a save class and make abstract `TaskSave IEmployeeTask.GetSave()` and `IEmployeeTask.LoadFrom(TaskSave save)` and implement a class for every task with some ugly `public readonly int referenceId`s inside, but If there is a chance I could avoid creating all those classes AND keep code clean, I would love to know if it's possible.

Comment: Why can't you restart the task? Can't you call `StartCoroutine(task.PerformTask())` again? I have a little trouble understanding your problem. Is this about saving the tasks to disk for use between sessions or do you mean saving as in pausing the task during a session?

Comment: I cannot restart it because it would be stupid if something in the task would be done two or more times. I have to save it externally and then re-create the tasks state.

Comment: What do you mean by `restarting`? Do you mean saving the task to disk to recreate later, or pausing and resuming a task?

Comment: By restarting I mean starting it once again. No matter if it was just paused and then started from beginning or saved and started from beginning or whatever

Comment: edited example a little in SomeTask1 - lets assume the employee reached destination and now is doing the thing and we wait for him to do it. Now we save the game and exit. After that I would like to resume the game and see that my employee skipped walking and is doing the thing.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Saving enumerator state](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wesdyer/2006/01/13/saving-the-state-of-enumerators/)

Comment: On second thought your case is different because you're using delegates and you won't be able to serialize that. Maybe to construct your tasks, use reflection and external file (list of methods) to run delegates dynamically? Gives you much wider playing field. Even queuing the delegates and getting/saving an int index (state) externally would do (but you'd lose references made along the way).

Comment: @Camile thanks, that sounds usefull and I should have done that much earlier :/ well, I think this is called experience. 
References should not be a problem, those are assigned in constructor, or could be created in loading. Only problem left is creating all those save structures and keeping it clean or being lazy and e.g. create one save struct with object[] as save data

Comment: For SomeTask1 i could hold something like: ```IEnumerator[] steps = { FirstStep, SecondStep }```, where *Step is a coroutine, and then ```PerformTask``` would invoke those steps in a ```for``` loop. This will lead to saving an ```int``` - index of current/next step to execute. Am I correct?

Comment: A simple answer would be to represent the individual steps by separate objects, then serialize them to JSON. Then, make a factory that can construct tasks. In my opinion, you are overcomplicating this. You want to save data about a task, not about its behavior. If you have `Step` objects, then the `Task` object could simply be an array of `Step`s and an `integer` pointing to the current step. This entire structure is serializable.

Comment: @Zimano thanks, factory will be usefull, and creating ```Step```s instead of coroutines would be a way to keep code clean

Comment: The key is to separate the behavioral aspects from the data-driven ones. A task or step within a task can still be started by a coroutine, but a task or step's state is defined by data (not its behavior); which you can serialize and deserialize. The factory's responsibility could be to deserialize a saved task, recreate the state and return the complete Task object. The `PerformTask` method could then simply check which step has to be run, akin to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

What I know after reading comments under question:

First of all I should have divided more complex taks into a structure of single atomic `Step`s which contain data about current step in the whole task. Then save which task and which step is currently running along with his data required to perform it.

Next there has to be a factory, that know how to recreate the task with current step from saved data.